# Unhandled Exception Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am new to active directory and i am trying to display details from the group category in Active Directory. Here is my code for the following:

```
entry = new DirectoryEntry(strPath);

DirectoryEntry schema = entry.SchemaEntry;
System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher myNewSearcher = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(entry);

mySearcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=*)");

foreach (System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult resEnt in mySearcher.FindAll())
{
    Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + resEnt.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Last Name : " + resEnt.Properties["sn"][0].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("SAM account name   : " + resEnt.Properties["samAccountName"][0].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("User principal name: " + resEnt.Properties["userPrincipalName"][0].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The error that I am getting is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll  Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Can I get some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AD properties might not be set - and in this case, you call to `.Properties[..][0]` will cause this exception.

You need to check for every property returned from the `DirectorySearcher` whether it's set - or not:

```
if(resEnt.Properties["givenName"] != null && resEnt.Properties["givenName"].Count > 0) {
   Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + resEnt.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString());
}
```